# Java decoding back from UTF-8 Character into emojis

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I'm working on a mobile app project, I'm getting the encoded version of the message with emojis to save and send a notification. When I send the exact data that I get will show some special characters instead of the emojis in the notification. I'm trying to decode that text before sending the notification in java, however, I didn't find any solution to decode the UTF-8 text back to the emojis.

Front end team using the `Xamarin forum`, and they are using the following codes for encoding the message into `UTF-8`.

```
message = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(msgData);
```

I have tried the following in my java method

```
Original message = hi ❤️
encodedMsg = "hi+%F0%9F%98%8D%F0%9F%99%82%F0%9F%A5%B0%F0%9F%92%AA%F0%9F%98%84%E2%9D%A4%EF%B8%8F%F0%9F%98%80%F0%9F%98%98";
String message = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(encodedMsg, "UTF-8");
```

but it returns the following error

> URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern

How can I decode the message back into a normal message with emojis using java?

Comment: What is the version of Java you are using? It works on Java 11.

Comment: Could you try to escape `%` symbol by `%%` or `\%`?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Java version is v9.0

Comment: It also works in Java 8.

Comment: @dehasi I have tried the same you suggested, that also results in the same error